# How do I make the inner loop consider each iteration of the outer loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, bioinformatics

Three-letter set, composed of `'A', 'U', 'G' or 'C'`, is defined as codon. Each codon corresponds to the one of 20 letter. Set of those letters (amino acids) is defined as protein. The file "codons.txt" contains codons and corresponding letters.

The problem is next: The inner for loop works only once — it compares lines from the txt file only with the first codon. Then, as I understand, the method skips the inner loop.

Code:

```
path = r'C:\Users\...\codons.txt'
f = open(path, 'r')

def prot(DNA):
    protein = ''
    a = True
    for i in range (0, len(DNA)-2,3):
        codon = DNA[i:i+3:1]
        print(codon)
        for line in f:
            if line[0:3:1] == codon:
                protein += line[4:5:1]
                print(protein)
    return protein


prot('AGUCAGGAUAGUCUUA')
```

Output:

```
 AGU
 S
 CAG
 GAU
 AGU
 CUU
```

The  question is next: How to make the inner loop work for each codon?

Comment: Swap loops - let the outer will be loop for iterating over lines in file; and inner - comparing with codons.

Comment: The inner loop works as documented.  @kosist gave you the canonical solution.  If you truly want to read the file (a slow process) multiple times, then you need to `reset` the file in each outer loop.  An extreme way to do this is to close and reopen the file.

Comment: You open the file right at the beginning, outside of the loops. Once you have iterated over all lines with the first execution of the inner loop, your "cursor" is at the end of the file, where there is nothing more to read for the following loop executions. You either have to open (and close!) the file in the innermost loop (very slow, since you have to read the file lots of times), or switch the loops, like @kosist suggests, so that the file only gets loaded once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating over a file (`for line in f:`), it stops when reaching the end of the file.

You can either:

- reset the file reader position to the start of the file using [`f.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)
- or change the order of the loops, so that you only iterate once over the file.

  ```
  def prot(DNA):
      protein = ''

      with open(path, 'r') as f:
          for line in f:
              for i in range (0, len(DNA)-2,3):
                  codon = DNA[i:i+3:1]
                  print(codon)

                      if line[0:3:1] == codon:
                          protein += line[4:5:1]
                          print(protein)

      return protein
  ```